# how to inject "memcache" to service.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached, session-cookies

I installed memcache lib and added it to

```
framework:  
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.memcache
```

but when I trying to use it I get this error

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]  
  You have requested a non-existent service "session.handler.memcache".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `memcache` or `memcached`? 
These are two different extensions, so be aware of that.
And I suggest to use `memcached`, `memcache` is dead.

Serivce `session.handler.memcache` is not defined, so you have to define one implementing `SessionHandlerInterface`, in your case `MemcacheSessionHandler`.

First, we need to define memcache instance as a service, so we can pass it to `MemcacheSessionHandler` constructor:

```
memcache:
    class: \Memcache
calls:
    - [ addServer, [ %host_parameter%, %port_parameter% ]]
```

Then, your session handler:

```
session.handler.memcache:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
        arguments: [@memcache]
```

You can also use a bundle like `cache/adapter-bundle` to register a PSR-6 compatible service (or even a symfony cache component, introduced in 3.1) and use `Psr6SessionHandler`.

If you want to use `memcached`, it's almost the same configuration-wise.

Comment: i get this error after injection ?

  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]           
  The definition for "calls" has no class. If you intend to inject this servi  
  ce dynamically at runtime, please mark it as synthetic=true. If this is an   
  abstract definition solely used by child definitions, please add abstract=t  
  rue, otherwise specify a class to get rid of this error.

Comment: but i get this error now   The service "memcache" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "host_p   
  arameter".

Comment: `%host_parameter%` represents a parameter called `host_parameter`. You can use your own name (`memcache_host`?) defining a parameter in `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` (with example value) and then in `app/config/parameters.yml` with a proper value. http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

Comment: i get this erorr Cannot dump definition because of invalid class name ('\\Memcache')

because this line     class: \Memcache

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has it's own component: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html

You have to configure it first in your `/config/packages/framework.yaml`:

```
framework:
  cache:
    pools:
      memcached_service:
        adapter: cache.adapter.memcached
        public: true
        provider: 'memcached://memcached:11211'
```

Now you can inject your Memcached service wherever you want (`services.yaml`):

```
App\Service\SomeService:
  arguments:
    - "@memcached_service"
```